# Remove lightroom from second monitor

Tags: lightroom, software, adobe

I accidentally put lightroom over both of my monitors and I cannot work out how to remove the right view. How do I make lightroom only show on 1 monitor

[image]

Comment: Did you try just click-n-pull?

Comment: No luck with the ol' click-n-pull!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Dual Monitor mode is activated by the Second Window button.

[image: Second Window button]

To close the second window just click this button again.

More on [Adobe help page](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/displaying-library-second-monitor.html).

Comment: Or you can press F11

Comment: You're a f*ing saviour! Lightroom's menus _suck_